# .htaccess deny access to specific dynamically generated url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to restrict access to a specific URL that's being generated, by IP address. For example:

http://www.domain.com/section.php/123/1/some-nice-text

can not be accessed by the IP 123.45.67.89.

So far, I've got:

```
<Limit GET POST HEAD>
  order allow,deny
  deny from 123.45.67.89
  allow from all
</Limit>
```

but this blocks access to all the site for that IP.

I can't put the htacess in that path, as it doesn't actually exist. How can I edit the Limit condition to specify a path?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use mod_rewrite. Something like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =123.45.67.89
RewriteRule ^section.php/123/1/some-nice-text - [R=404,L,NC]
```

(Untested / season to taste.)

Update: For multiple addresses, you can use regexen and/or multiple RewriteConds combined with [OR]:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =123.45.67.89 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.45\.67\.9[0-4]$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.4\.56\.
RewriteRule ^section.php/123/1/some-nice-text - [R=404,L,NC]
```

(Still untested etc.)

Comment: I have a number of IP addresses that I want to disable access for, is there a logical way of wrapping this somehow so that I can apply it for multiple IPs?